git with firewall and captive portal
Our firewall requires a seperate login with 2fa before we can access the git repository.
Is there a way to open the login Site automatically in an browser when git is not able to find the repo?
(Firewall sends a http 200 and the portal directly)

This seems to be a git-related networking question?

I think it's a git configuration question?

I don't think git has the means to configure networking?

I don't want git to configure networking. Just open a browser when there is a captive portal instead a repo on the configured url. Or a Script running before the git action is performed in which I can check, if there is a captive portal or a git repo accesssible.

This isn't something that git specifically deals with. You'll likely need to write a script to do this. This doesn't seem to be a programming question since a similar thing as been asked elsewhere

@H_G Git surely cannot do that by itself and I don't think there is a turn-key 3rd-party solution. You need to write something yourself similar to https://github.com/hickford/git-credential-oauth — this is a Git credential helper that opens a browser to authenticate.
